# I want to center two buttons inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I center those two buttons in JS:

```
// create a sort by alphabet button
var sortabc = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn">Sort alphabetically</a>').toggle(
    function(){
        $("#tags ul li").tsort({order:"asc"});
    },  
    function(){
        $("#tags ul li").tsort({order:"desc"});
    }       
    );
$('#tags').append(sortabc);     

// create a sort by alphabet button 
var sortstrength = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn">Sort by strength</a>').toggle(
    function(){
        $("#tags ul li").tsort({order:"desc",attr:"class"});
    },  
    function(){
        $("#tags ul li").tsort({order:"asc",attr:"class"});
    }       
    );
$('#tags').append(sortstrength);
```

At this moment I get them like this:
Button 1 Button 2

I want them in the middle of the div.

Answer (score 5):

With CSS, in your style sheet:

```
#tags {
    text-align : center;
}
```

With jQuery, setting that same CSS property:

```
$('#tags').css("text-align", "center");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z77Lm/

Comment: Or create a `text-center` class, and then use `.addClass()`

Answer (score -2):

Try using  tag inside the div:

```
<div>
<center>
...BUTTONS
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated in favour of CSS.